# Assigning Array Value Gives Undefined Key

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array of 100 trucks. Each truck holds several boxes.
I insert the first box of each truck by splicing from the box array to the truck array:

```
removed = allBoxes.splice(x, 1)[0];
trucks[i] = {0: removed};
```

Because I know it's the first box, I can put the `{0:`. But to add the next box, I want it to be dynamic.
I can insert it at the right place, but the key is `undefined` instead of `1` for the next box.

```
removed = allBoxes.splice(x, 1)[0];
trucks[i][trucks[i].length] = removed;
```

You can see the results here:  Instead of `undefined:`, can it say `1`?  Whenever I try to add a variable in the array, it just writes out the variable string, not the value.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you want to use `.map()`

Comment: trucks[i] is defined as an object rather than an array, so it has no 'length' property.

Comment: In case the array is empty in the beginning, just use `allBoxes.push(obj)` and it will add the `obj` to the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JordanBurnett mentioned, it wasn't an array. I had to count how many objects were in the array.  Using the below code (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object)) gave the desired result:

```
var size = Object.keys(trucks[i]).length;
trucks[i][size] = removed;
```

[image]